# How to predict the width of an HTML Element in order to made a CSS transition on the opacity and the width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-transitions

- I'm dealing with a `span` node with an `innerText`.
- At runtime, I will change the `innerText` so the `offsetWidth` of the node will change, depending on the future-`innerText` length.
- I need to foresee the future-`offsetWidth` in order to deal with `transition` of the width itself, via CSS.
- In this case, in particular, I need to make a `transition` **both** on the `opacity` and the `width` of the `span` element, so I can't change the `inneText` immediately.

How I can predict the exact value of the `width`?

More generally, there is a way to "simulate" DOM changes in order to know the *future-CSS-properties*?

**Possible starting code snippet**

```js
let h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
let span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
h1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(span.innerText == "Better") {
    span.innerText = "Awsome";
  } else {
    span.innerText = "Better";
  }
})
```

```css
h1 span {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  transition-property: all;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello <span>Awsome</span> World!</h1>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You can duplicate the element and do the calculations on that.

Comment: Maybe you can create a copy of the element with the new text outside the viewport so it gets calculated.

Comment: For now, I've not the yet the code. The problem is that I need a "secure" computed style, so If I clone the node the only way to compute the style is to append that in the same place of the cloned. I can't do it because It will be shown before the opacity transition. I need to "simulate" that, without really doing that. Better if I will not clone the node and just make the transition to the future-width, remove the opacity, change the text and than re-add the opacity. It's quite challenging.

Comment: Code snippet added.

Comment: You don't need a clone, just set the text, then retrieve it. Retrieving the changed DOM forces re-calculation, which after you can read the computed style. Nothing will be rendered before the script is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in my comment, you can clone the element, set its content to the content you want, and measure its width. Then, you can change the original width to the width you get from the cloned element.

Like this:

```js
let h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
let span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
span.style.width = `${span.clientWidth}px`;
h1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const nextWord = getNextWord();
  const featureWidth = getFeatureWidth(nextWord);
  span.style.color = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
  span.style.width = `${featureWidth}px`;
  setTimeout(() => {
    span.textContent = nextWord;
    span.style.color = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
  }, 300);
});

function getNextWord() {
  if(span.innerText == "Better") {
    return "Awsome";
  }
  return "Better";
}

function getFeatureWidth(word) {
  const clonedSpan = document.createElement('span');
  clonedSpan.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute;z-index: -1');
  clonedSpan.textContent = word;
  h1.appendChild(clonedSpan);
  const width = clonedSpan.clientWidth;
  h1.removeChild(clonedSpan);
  return width;
}
```

```css
h1 span {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello <span>Awsome</span> World!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Mosh Feu solution, here's a rework of the case:

```js
let h1;
let span;
let width;
let words;
let opacity;
let button;
button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
element = document.getElementById("word");
width = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("width");
words = [
  'Better',
  'Great',
  'Best Ever',
  'Incredible',
  'Awsome'
];
element.setAttribute('style', `
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity = 1});
  width: ${width};
`);
let iterator = words.values();
function changeWord() {
  let word;
  let next;
  let width;
  next = iterator.next();
  if (next.done) {
    iterator = words.values();
    next = iterator.next();
  }
  word = next.value;
  width = getFeatureWidth(word);
  element.setAttribute('style', `
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity = 0});
    width: ${width};
  `);
  setTimeout(() => {
    element.textContent = word;
    element.setAttribute('style', `
      color: rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity = 1});
      width: ${width};
    `);
  }, 300);
}
button.addEventListener("click", changeWord);

function getFeatureWidth(word) {
  let clone;
  let width;
  let parent;
  clone = element.cloneNode(true);
  clone.setAttribute('style', `
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1
  `);
  clone.textContent = word;
  parent = element.parentElement;
  parent.appendChild(clone);
  width = window.getComputedStyle(clone).getPropertyValue("width");
  parent.removeChild(clone);
  return width;
}
```

```css
#word {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  display: inline-block;
  transition-property: color, width;
  transition-duration: .3s, .3s;
  transition-delay: 0, 0;
  transition-timing-function: ease, ease;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Hello <span id="word">Awsome</span> World!
</h1>
<button>Next</button>
```